# SwiftUI ask notification permission on start without button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to request notification permission from the user on startup without forcing the user to click a specific button.
Xcode 14.2

My application structure:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications


@main
struct RSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now where should I add this code to request permission?

```
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
    
    if let error = error {
        // Handle the error here.
    }
    // Enable or disable features based on the authorization.
}
```

(from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)

I know I can add it as a function call to the button, but I would like to request access without the user having to click anything, so basically when the view is initialized.

Comment: Look at `onAppear`

Comment: It's a better user experience if you don't ask permission for something until the user performs an action that needs the permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are modifying App root View. So you can put your code into either `init` or `onAppear`. I'd suggest to use latter (`onAppear`) just to follow best practices. SwiftUI creates all the views immediately, even destination views for navigation links, which means that initializers are run immediately. While code placed in `onAppear` modifier is called only when the view is shown. So your code can look like this:

```
import SwiftUI


@main
struct RSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .onAppear() {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle the error here.
                    }
                    // Enable or disable features based on the authorization.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications


@main
struct RSApp: App {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    init() {
        registerForNotification()
    }
    
    func registerForNotification() {
        //For device token and push notifications.
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        let center : UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        //        center.delegate = self
        
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound , .alert , .badge ], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            if ((error != nil)) { UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() }
            else {
                
            }
        })
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```